# .NET Core AutoMapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

.NET Core application. I am trying to use Automapper but results in the below error.

> ```
> .Net Core Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping
> ```

I have below setup in startup.cs

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });

            IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Then I am using profiles.

```
  public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<Geography, GeographyEntity>();
            this.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>();
        }

    }
```

I am using auto mapper as below

```
 Model1 model = this.Mapper.Map<Model1>(Model2);
```

Below are the models

```
 public partial class Model1
    {
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public string SarNo { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public int CId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Model2 C { get; set; }
    }

public class Model2
{
    public int SNo { get; set; }

    public string SarNo { get; set; }

    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }
    
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

}
```

I get below error in auto mapper.

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
> or unsupported mapping.

can someone help me to understand this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>();` will create map from `Model1` to `Model2`, so this should work:

```
Model2 model = this.Mapper.Map<Model2>(new Model1());
```

If you want it vise versa either change the registration to:

```
this.CreateMap<Model2, Model1>();
```

or add [`ReverseMap`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) to have bidirectional one:

```
this.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Hi Guru, I am not having issue with mapping but I am not able to run my code itself, It throws above error. Thanks

Comment: @Niranjangodbole when does it throw? On this line: `Model1 model = this.Mapper.Map<Model1>(Model2);` ?

Comment: Then please try to correct your mapping as I wrote. change `this.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>();` to `this.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>().ReverseMap();` in your `MappingProfile`.

Comment: This worked like charm. But  why I should use ReverseMap?

Comment: @Niranjangodbole it depends on use case. in you provided case the `this.CreateMap<Model2, Model1>()` solution which i wrote about should work too.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. I spent hours so I thought I would mention it here.

I had different projects for Api, domains/entities, DTOs, and mapping profiles.

There were two issues.
First, I forgot to mark the DTO mapping profiles classes as public.
Second, I had the registered automapper in startup class as below:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

The above line works fine if your mapping profiles are in the same assembly. In my case mapping profiles were in a different assembly, and therefore this was not picking up the profiles. To resolve this, I used the following:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.Load("Your assembly name"));
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that. I was about to lose my mind.

Comment: ı guess here `AddAutoMapper()` wants to know: in which Assembly you have defined mapping profiles. i was using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` but it was in my `Program.cs` after reading your answer, i have coded a ServiceCollectionExtension for my Application.csproj project(here it gets the assembly) and then i add AutoMapper via this extension. it worked. thank you for your guidence

Comment: Making the model public vs internal fixed it for me.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 8):

In some tutorials instead of

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });

        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

using

```
service.AddAutoMapper({profile assembly marker types});
```

Usually, in those tutorials, they were referring to startup. In practical that assembly marker should be your profile mapping class. In this case, it should be

```
service.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

In net core 6 I solved the problem with the @Amit recomendation above.

It is, In Proram.cs I had:  `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));`

as automapper page recommended and I was receiving the missing mapping exception.

I changed to the following and solve the problem:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
```

Comment: Where does it say that? :) I see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu this is the documentation page I read https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/ . As you can see there, for net core 6, is recomending to add "builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));" but I discovered you need to put the typeof to the class where your AutoMapperProfile is. I hope this helps.

Comment: That's not the AM documentation. That's some page on the internet with outdated content. There is no such code in the AM documentation.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu ok. This is the code is working properly in my app, I shared it because maybe it helps to anyone else. If you want to look for the official documentation to use it. Go ahead. Good luck!